# azure-storage-datalake headers like CamelFileName and camelfilelength are not present in headers after file transfer

Tags: apache-camel

We have created route with consumer as file and producer as azure-storage-datalake.
File transfer is successful .After file transfer , headers like **CamelFileName** and **CamelFileLength** are not present in **headers** object of exchange.
I want to set/add headers to exchange before file transfer and use them after file transfer for further processing (tracking) but with above route

(file->azure-storage-blob) we are not able access headers which were set before file transfer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.